# How to make the following code work with flow js annotations? Using Object.create()

Tags: javascript, flowtype, es6-class

Please check this: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAQTAG9UwwBzAUwBcws4A7agCgEoAuMWgCwEsCZChQBOdAK6imYAPIAjAFbUMtAHR5c-Sk1YLlqtRnHZabPoPYAaHgNztyYAL6oXmHPjAAhMNQAeZkwAJgTEJG4AbtiiYPJgALxgLEheHADcqFExGAmxRvAsqEA

In the following code I get an error on my `clone` call:

```
/* @flow */

class A {
  get clone(): this {
     return Object.assign(Object.create(this), this)
  }
}

class B extends A {}

var b = new B();
var c = b.clone
```

I get an error: Covariant property `clone` incompatible with contravariant use in call of method `assign`.

How to annotate this, please correct my example.

Comment: What you really want is `Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this)`

Comment: Thanks but I get flowtype error: This type is incompatible with the expected return type of this. [See Code example here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAQTAG9UwwBzAUwBcws4A7agCgEoAuMWgCwEsCZChQBOdAK6imYAPIAjAFbUMtAHR5c-Sk1YLlqtRnHZabfSvU1aABVFxaDgJ4AHarKis+g9uwA0PAK47ORgAL6oEZg4+GAAQmDUAB5mTAAmBMQkUQBu2KJg8mAAvGAsSHEcANyoeQUYJYVG8CyoQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now (by casting to any):

```
/* @flow */

class A {
  get clone(): this {
     return Object.assign((Object.create(this): any), this)
  }
}

class B extends A {}

var b = new B()
var c = b.clone
```